# How to apply "STRIPE_SECRET_KEY" to Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

Currently, what I am having are simple `ChargeRequest` and `PaymentStatus` as my entities, `StripeService`, `ChargeController` and `CheckoutController` as my controllers.

I am trying to set up environment variables in **.bashrc**:

```
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY=my_key
```

However, still getting an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'STRIPE_SECRET_KEY' in value "${STRIPE_SECRET_KEY}"
```

Here is the *StripeService*:

```
package com.edoyou.k2sbeauty.services.implementations;

import com.edoyou.k2sbeauty.entities.model.ChargeRequest;
import com.stripe.Stripe;
import com.stripe.exception.APIConnectionException;
import com.stripe.exception.APIException;
import com.stripe.exception.CardException;
import com.stripe.exception.InvalidRequestException;
import com.stripe.model.Charge;
import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class StripeService {

  @Value("${STRIPE_SECRET_KEY}")
  private String secretKey;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    Stripe.apiKey = secretKey;
  }
  public Charge charge(ChargeRequest chargeRequest)
      throws AuthenticationException, InvalidRequestException,
      APIConnectionException, CardException, APIException, com.stripe.exception.AuthenticationException {
    Map<String, Object> chargeParams = new HashMap<>();
    chargeParams.put("amount", chargeRequest.getAmount());
    chargeParams.put("currency", chargeRequest.getCurrency());
    chargeParams.put("description", chargeRequest.getDescription());
    chargeParams.put("source", chargeRequest.getStripeToken());
    return Charge.create(chargeParams);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely reason that this isn't working is that you are not exporting the environment variable from your .bashrc file.  Bash environment variables need to be `exported` to be available to child processes.

Change the variable declaration in your .bashrc file to this:

`export STRIPE_SECRET_KEY=my_key`

Source your .bashrc file with `. .bashrc`, then verify the environment variable exists before starting your service.  You must start the service in a process that was spawned off of your `.bashrc` changes.  For instance, this environment variable isn't visible to your ide that was opened before making those changes.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using the [Java dotEnv module](https://github.com/cdimascio/dotenv-java)?  You could then add a `.env` file in the `app/` directory to set the necessary environment variable

```bash
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY=sk_test_XXXXXXXXXXX
```

Then you can access this and load it into the Stripe client library like so

```java
import io.github.cdimascio.dotenv.*;
...
Dotenv dotenv = Dotenv.load();
Stripe.apiKey = dotenv.get("STRIPE_SECRET_KEY");
```